# AWS find .cer and .key file

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, openssl

I have `httpd` running on AWS EC2. I have requested SSL certificate and the web server is running fine on https.
Now, I want to attach the certificate with a WebRTC [`easyrtc`](https://easyrtc.com/docs/easyrtc_server_ssl.php) server which requires `.crt` and `.key` files and I have no clue where to find it.

I have searched in aws console Certificate Manager but couldn't find the files. But I guess since the webserver is running on https already, the file should be there in the file system.

I tried below `localhost.crt` file which is `/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt` and `localhost.key` and the server is running fine, but the browser is throwing the warning because of may be self-signed certificate.
[image]

Please help.
I do not have much knowledge about SSL certificates and installation.

Comment: Where did you get your certificate from - is it self signed? Did you generate your own private key? You could of course generate another key / certificate using any provider you like, such as Let's Encrypt, which is free.

Comment: Not self-signed. I have requested the certificate from AWS web console.

Comment: As per EEAA's answer, no you didn't. I suggest you hire a consultant with your encryption issues.

Comment: as @Tim suggested you can generate perfectly valid TLS cert public/private keys from https://letsencrypt.org/  for free ...  their tutorials are very clear and do work ...  have fun

Comment: @ScottStensland If I use those certificates, will users get the ssl certificate browser warnings?

Comment: no they are perfectly valid ... letencrypt is an industry collective who's goal is to make it easy to transition from http to https ... their tooling also includes a TLS cert refresh script that allows you to renew the certs prior to their 90 day expiry date ... there are no browser warnings and  infact I would start to consider suspect anyone who chooses not to use letsencrypt !

Comment: Done! Installed successfully. Thanks a lot man. Never heard of this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS certificate manager certs can only be used with ELB and Cloudfront. They cannot be downloaded and installed on your EC2 instance. For that, you will need to purchase a signed certificate from a public trusted CA (I recommend SSLMate, for their dead-simple CLI tools for purchasing certs).

Comment: This is entirely why ACM is so good. It makes the SSL cert harder to compromise because it's not stored on the server or anything we can access